# How to generate Session dynamically in yii?

Tags: session, session-variables, yii2

I'm trying to generate a session ID.

I set the session ID with the following:

```
$session = new Session;
$session->open();
$session->set('user', '1234');
```

Instead of setting, I want to generate the session ID dynamically.

Comment: What's the point of that?

Comment: Here im setting session id as user=1234. instead of that, it want to generate dynamic

Comment: If you want to set the session id you have to call [setId()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#setId%28%29-detail) before you open the session. With you code you just set the value 'user' in the already opened session.